# iOS Retain count

Tags: ios, objective-c, reference-counting

What is the *retain count* of val and arr in the below code snippet ?

```
NSString *val=@"qaz";

NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[arr addObject:val];
```

Considering we're in MRC.

What is the *retain count* of str1,str2,str3 and str4 ?

```
NSString *str1=[[NSString alloc]initwithString:@"str"];

NSString * str2=[str1 copy];

NSString * str3=[str1 retain];

NSString * str4=str3;
```

I am confused with retain count somebody help me with explanation

Comment: You are not supposed to care about the actual number.

Comment: The concepts of memory management takes quite some text to explain and Apple has written a very good guide for it; [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *val=@"qaz"; // @"qaz" Counting = 1, handled by val

NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // NSMutableArray Counting = 1, handled by arr

[arr addObject:val];  // nothing changes
```

MRC

```
NSString *str1=[[NSString alloc]initwithString:@"str"];  // @"str" Counting = 1

NSString * str2=[str1 copy]; // @"str" Counting = 1; the "copy @"str"" Counting = 1 handled by str2    
NSString * str3=[str1 retain]; // @"str" Counting = 2; the "copy @"str"" Counting = 1 

NSString * str4=str3; // nothing changes
```

Alloc/init, retain: increase Reference Counting.

Copy: create another object with Counting = 1, not increase Counting of copied object

Release: decrease Reference Counting.

In ARC mode, you don't have to call release, just need to set pointer = nil. Object will be release if there is no pointer handles it.

Comment: You can refer the link of @Mats https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html